# Can one leverage std::basic_string to implement a string having a length limitation?

Tags: c++, templates, string, stl, stdstring

I'm working with a low-level API that accepts a `char*` and numeric value to represent a string and its length, respectively.  My code uses `std::basic_string` and calls into these methods with the appropriate translation.  Unfortunately, many of these methods accept string lengths of varying size (i.e. max(`unsigned char`), max(`short`), etc...) and I'm stuck writing code to make sure that my string instances do not exceed the maximum length prescribed by the low-level API.

By default, the maximum length of an `std::basic_string` instance is bound by the maximum value of `size_t` (either max(`unsigned int`) or max(`__int64`)).  Is there a way to manipulate the  traits and allocator implementations of a `std::basic_string` implementation so that I may specify my own type to use in place of `size_t`?  By doing so, I am hoping to leverage any existing bounds checks within the `std::basic_string` implementation so I don't have to do so when performing the translation.

My initial investigation suggests that this is not possible without writing my own string class, but I'm hoping that I overlooked something :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can pass a custom allocator to `std::basic_string` which has a max size of whatever you want. This should be sufficient. Perhaps something like this:

```
template <class T>
class my_allocator {
public:
    typedef T              value_type;

    typedef std::size_t    size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T*             pointer;
    typedef const T*       const_pointer;
    typedef T&             reference;
    typedef const T&       const_reference;

    pointer address(reference r) const             { return &r; }
    const_pointer address(const_reference r) const { return &r; }

    my_allocator() throw() {}

    template <class U>
    my_allocator(const my_allocator<U>&) throw() {}

    ~my_allocator() throw() {}

    pointer allocate(size_type n, void * = 0) {
        // fail if we try to allocate too much
        if((n * sizeof(T))> max_size()) { throw std::bad_alloc(); }
        return static_cast<T *>(::operator new(n * sizeof(T)));
    }

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type) {
        return ::operator delete(p);
    }

    void construct(pointer p, const T& val) { new(p) T(val); }
    void destroy(pointer p)                 { p->~T(); }

    // max out at about 64k
    size_type max_size() const throw() { return 0xffff; }

    template <class U>
    struct rebind { typedef my_allocator<U> other; };

    template <class U>
    my_allocator& operator=(const my_allocator<U> &rhs) {
        (void)rhs;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Then you can probably do this:

```
typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, my_allocator<char> > limited_string;
```

**EDIT:** I've just done a test to make sure this works as expected. The following code tests it.

```
int main() {
    limited_string s;
    s = "AAAA";
    s += s;
    s += s;
    s += s;
    s += s;
    s += s;
    s += s;
    s += s; // 512 chars...
    s += s;
    s += s;
    s += s;
    s += s;
    s += s;
    s += s; // 32768 chars...
    s += s; // this will throw std::bad_alloc

    std::cout << s.max_size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << s.size() << std::endl;
}
```

That last `s += s` will put it over the top and cause a `std::bad_alloc` exception, (since my limit is just short of 64k). Unfortunately gcc's `std::basic_string::max_size()` implementation does not base its result on the allocator you use, so it will still claim to be able to allocate more. (I'm not sure if this is a bug or not...).

But this will definitely allow you impose hard limits on the sizes of strings in a simple way. You could even make the max size a template parameter so you only have to write the code for the allocator once.

Comment: I would have added an int template parameter <typename T, int N> and had max_size() return N; then he can do typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, my_allocator<char, 256> > my256string;

Comment: I think exposing `size_type` as a template argument would be beneficial as then the user is free to choose which `size_type` is best suited for a given string instance.  Then, partial template specialization will help with making this type play nice with `basic_string`.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Evan Teran about his solution. This is just a modification of his solution no more:

```
template <typename Type, typename std::allocator<Type>::size_type maxSize>
struct myalloc : std::allocator<Type>
{
    // hide std::allocator[ max_size() & allocate(...) ]

    std::allocator<Type>::size_type max_size() const throw()
    {
        return maxSize;
    }
    std::allocator<Type>::pointer allocate
        (std::allocator<Type>::size_type n, void * = 0)
    {
        // fail if we try to allocate too much
        if((n * sizeof(Type))> max_size()) { throw std::bad_alloc(); }
        return static_cast<Type *>(::operator new(n * sizeof(Type)));
    }
};
```

Be aware you should not use polymorphism at all with `myalloc`. So this is disastrous:

```
// std::allocator doesn't have a virtual destructor
std::allocator<char>* alloc = new myalloc<char>;
```

You just use it as if it is a separate type, it is safe in following case:

```
myalloc<char, 1024> alloc; // max size == 1024
```

Comment: Yea, I just thought of making the max size a template parameter. Unfortunately, I don't think your solution will work as is. Because (at least gcc's) string implementation does not base it's max size on the allocator's max size. So I had to make `allocate(...)` throw if it requested more than `max_size` bytes.

Comment: @Evan Your solution is nice, you got my +1 btw. I'll add more code for `allocate` as you clarified :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you create a class with std::string as parent and override c_str()?
Or define your own c_str16(), c_str32(), etc and implement translation there?

Comment: Most of the standard library is not intended to be inherited from (they have no virtual methods). So this is not advisable.