# limit stl's vector max_size

Tags: c++, stl

How can I limit STL vector's max_size? Eventually by specialization. An example would be welcome.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591591/can-one-leverage-stdbasic-string-to-implement-a-string-having-a-length-limitati/1591758#1591758

Comment: why do you want to limit vector's size? Anyway consider use of boost::circular_buffer or boost::array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do this is to replace the allocator. Note that vector and string are the only containers that actually check their allocators max_size right now. The idea is that since these containers guarantee that the elements are stored in contiguous memory, the container asks the allocator just how many elements the allocator can handle.

This is the idea

```
template<class T>
struct MyAllocator:std::allocator<T>
{
     template <class U> 
     struct rebind { typedef MyAllocator<U> other; };

     typedef typename std::allocator<T>::size_type size_type;

     MyAllocator(size_type sz=1234)
     : m_maxsize(sz)
     {}

     size_type max_size() const { return m_maxsize; }

  private:
     size_type m_maxsize;
};
```

then make a new vector

```
typedef std::vector<Type,MyAllocator<Type>> vec_t;
vec_t vec(vec_t::allocator_type(4567));
```

I haven't tried compiling this code, but it should work.

Comment: You left out the declaration of `maxsize`. In any case, stateless allocators are better, so it should be implemented as a template parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the bug report. Virtually all std library implementation  support stateful allocators, however you are right that the C++03standard does not requires this support, so making it a template woould make it strictly conformant and smaller.

Answer (score 1):

`max_size` in `std::vector` isn't something you can alter. It's a constant specific for current vector, that shows how many elements of current type you can put in that vector (I guess it will depend on your system type)

So, for `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<double>` max_size will differ that much, as `int` and `double` differ.