# Is there any way to limit the size of an STL Map?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I want to implement some sort of lookup table in C++ that will act as a cache.  It is meant to emulate a piece of hardware I'm simulating.

The keys are non-integer, so I'm guessing a hash is in order. I have no intention of inventing the wheel so I intend to use `std::map` for this (though suggestions for alternatives are welcome).

The question is, is there any way to limit the *size* of the hash to emulate the fact that my hardware is of finite size?  I'd expect the hash's *insert* method to return an error message or throw an exception if the limit is reached.

If there is no such way, I'll simply check its size before trying to insert, but that seems like an inelegant way to do it.

Comment: What you can do is to throw `bad_alloc`, and that can be done by implementing your own allocator. Here is all what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591591/can-one-leverage-stdbasic-string-to-implement-a-string-having-a-length-limitati/1591758#1591758

Comment: A map is a tree, not a hash table structure. It will allow for lookups but will search in `O(log N)` (as compared to `O(1)` for an optimal hash)

Comment: @David: A map can be implemented however the author chose, so long as that implementation satisfies the STL complexity requirements for the type.  It's best not to imagine a given STL type implemented in any particular way - the complexity requirements are all that are guaranteed.

Comment: @Nick, I know that the standard does not require a concrete data structure, but the requirements in time complexity in the comment hold: lookup operations in a map are `O(log N)` in the standard. It is also a fact that all existing STL implementations do use trees internally for maps (so even if from a theoretical point of view the implication map => tree does not hold, from a pragmatic point of view it does). Part of the reason is that it is hard to come up with a different data structure for which all requirements in all operations that the standard makes hold.

Comment: The namespace is "std" not "stl", so I have edited the question to say "std::map" instead of "stl::map".

Comment: @Nick: A hash table requires that keys are hashable; trees require that keys are ordered. The C++ standard does require that `std::map` keys are sortable, but does not require them to be hashable. Also, itertion over a `std::map` has to iterate over all keys in that precise sort order. Hence, we can say for certain that the standard doesn't allow `std::map` to be a hashtable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First thing is that a `map` structure is not a `hash table`, but rather a balanced binary tree. This has an impact in the lookup times `O(log N)` instead of `O(1)` for an optimal hash implementation. This may or not affect your problem (if the number of actual keys and operations is small it can suffice, but the emulation of the cache can be somehow suboptimal.

The simplest solution that you can do is encapsulate the actual data structure into a class that checks the size in each insertion (size lookups *should* be implemented in constant time in all STL implementations) and fails if you are trying to add one too many elements.

```
class cache {
public:
   static const int max_size = 100;
   typedef std::map<key_t, value_t> cache_map_t;
   void add( key_t key, value_t value ) {
      cache_map_t::const_iterator it = m_table.find( key );
      if ( it != m_table.end() && m_table.size() == max_size ) { 
         // handle error, throw exception...
      } else {
         m_table.insert( it, std::make_pair(key,value) );
      }
   }
private:
   cache_map_t m_table;
};
// Don't forget, in just one translation unit:
const int cache::max_size;
```

Comment: The implementation details of a given std::map are outside the scope of the C++ specification.  There's no guarantee a map is a tree.

Comment: @Nick: true, but the complexity requirements for std::map in the standard don't leave much choice for the implementation. I challenge you to find a standard-conformant std::map implementation that's not a tree :)

Comment: I have already answered the equivalent to the comment in the question. Take all requirements from the standard and try to come up with a different implementation (i.e. try to implement an ever growing map for which insertions take `O(log N)` with a hash) or alternatively, mention one STL implementation for which maps are not balanced trees.

Comment: @Nick: As far as I know, only a tree or skip list can satisfy the constraints the standard places on a `map`/`set`. In any case, it is *not* a hash map. (And was always intended to be a tree.)

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to "automatically" limit the size of an `std::map`, simply because a "limited `std::map`" would not be an `std::map` anymore.

Wrap the `std::map` in a class of your own which just checks the size of the `std::map` against a constant before inserting, and does whatever you want in case the maximum size has been reached.

Answer (score 2):

If you're implementing LRU caches or similar, I've found [boost::bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) to be invaluable.  Use one index to be the primary "object ID" key (which can be an efficient vector view if you have a simple enumeration of objects), and the other index can be an ordered timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same use case. Though it might not align completely with the question but the concept seems similar.

```
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 5> myMap;
    myMap[0] = std::make_pair(1, 10);
    myMap[1] = std::make_pair(2, 20);
    myMap[2] = std::make_pair(3, 30);
    myMap[3] = std::make_pair(4, 40);
    myMap[4] = std::make_pair(5, 50);
    return 0;
}
```